# The expression is invalid inside an 'Include' operation using SQL view:

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to do Include() of my context using SQL view? I got this error msg:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'u.BookingStatus' is
> invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a
> property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared
> on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the
> 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty')

```
await _context.Set<vwTMDM>().Include(u => u.BookingStatus).ToListAsync();
```

PS: The purpose for using View is for Read Only data.

This is for my header view:

```
public class vwTMDM
{ 
    public string Courier { get; set; }
    public string Courier2 { get; set; }
    public string PlateNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal? Qty { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int ManId { get; set; }
    public string ManNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TMCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public List<vwTMDMStatus> BookingStatus { get; set; } = new List<vwTMDMStatus>();
} 

public class vwTMDMStatus
{ 
    [ForeignKey("ManId")]
    public int ManId { get; set; }
    public string ManNumber { get; set; }
    public string BookStatus { get; set; }
    public string InternalStatus { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

In my DBContext I declare below for my SQL View:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<vwTMDM>(e => {
            e.HasNoKey();
            e.ToView("vwGetTMDM");
        }); 
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<vwTMDMStatus>(e => {
            e.HasNoKey();
            e.ToView("vwGetTMDMStatus");
        });
```

Comment: Sure, view / query types can have navigations, but since `BookingStatus` doesn't follow an obvious naming convention, you'll need to define it explicitly.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman sorry to ask what do you mean `define it explicitly`? Thank you!

Comment: I think you have `[ForeignKey...` in the wrong place. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cdata-annotations-simple-key%2Csimple-key#foreign-key There are plenty of other examples on that page.